# Add Rows from the Same Range, no matter when the range location

Tags: excel, vba, insert, absolute

I have 3 tables for a real estate project. Each table is a simple summation of real estate properties, e.g. for apartments, 1 property has 100 units, the 2nd property has 200 units for a total sum of 300 units. The next table is also a simple summation but with different inputs for the same real estate properties in the first table, e.g. 1 property (the same as the above) has 50 1-bedroom units and 50 2-bedroom units; 2nd property has 100 1-bedroom units and 100 2-bedroom units, etc.

The challenge I have is when I want to add another real estate property to each table. My macro is a simple "EntireRow.Insert" function, but I always need the new property to be directly above the summation of all properties. When I do an insert, it shifts my reference cell down. How can I insert a new row always from this same summation range, even if that summation range moves down as I insert more properties?

Code is below. My `B10:E10` would shift to `B11:E11` after I run the macro the first time. If I need to do it again, it will not be successful because there is a new `B10:E10` after running the first macro. `Worksheets("Transaction").Range("B10:E10").EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: I would suggest having a blank row in between the sum and the data, including that blank row in the sum and inserting new rows about the blank row.

Comment: Thank you, I like this idea. How would I make that blank row always that specific reference range? When I insert a row once, that range moves down to a new reference.

Comment: For example if your data is in rows 2 to 10, put the totals on row 12 with a blank row on row 11.  Have to total row add row 2 thru 11.  Whenever, you insert a new row above the blank row, the blank row will move to row 12, the total will mode to row 13 and the total formula will now sum rows 2 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

### Insert Row Above Last

- Assuming that the last row will contain totals, the following will each time insert a row above it.
- Note that this may fail only if the worksheet is filtered.
- The initial formula in the totals row could be something like:

  ```
  =SUM(B$9:OFFSET(B10;-1;0))
  ```

  if cell `B9` contains a title (header).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertRowAboveLast(FirstCellRange As Range)
    If Not FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim cel As Range
        With FirstCellRange.Cells(1)
            Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                cel.EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub TESTinsertRowAboveLast()
    insertRowAboveLast ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10")
End Sub
```